# Android Studio - PDF Render Fragment code java

Tags: android, pdf

**Hello, I have an error when I click on my link that allows me to display my work that contains my pdf**

PDFRenderFragement the class is imported from another project. In this project the class is functional. The import of this project gave me this.

Activity PDFRenderFragment

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PDFRenderFragment extends Fragment {

private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
private PdfRenderer pdfRenderer;
private PdfRenderer.Page currentPage;
private ImageView image;
private Button btnPrevious;
private Button btnNext;

public PDFRenderFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.affichage_pdf, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Retain view references.
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    btnPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
    btnNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    //set buttons event
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(-1)); //previous button clicked
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(1)); //next button clicked

    int index = 0;
    // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
    if (null != savedInstanceState) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page", 0);
    }
    showPage(index);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        openRenderer(activity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Fragment", "Error occurred!");
        Log.e("Fragment", e.getMessage());
        activity.finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        closeRenderer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (null != currentPage) {
        outState.putInt("current_page", currentPage.getIndex());
    }
}

/**
 * Create a PDF renderer
 * @param activity
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void openRenderer(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    // Reading a PDF file from the assets directory.
    fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd("Protocole.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

    // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
    pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
}

/**
 * Closes PdfRenderer and related resources.
 */
private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
    if (null != currentPage) {
        currentPage.close();
    }
    pdfRenderer.close();
    fileDescriptor.close();
}

/**
 * Shows the specified page of PDF file to screen
 * @param index The page index.
 */
private void showPage(int index) {
    if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
        return;
    }
    // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
    if (null != currentPage) {
        currentPage.close();
    }
    //open a specific page in PDF file
    currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
    // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(), currentPage.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
    currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
    // showing bitmap to an imageview
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    updateUIData();
}

/**
 * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
 */
private void updateUIData() {
    int index = currentPage.getIndex();
    int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
    btnPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
    btnNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name, index + 1, pageCount));
}

private View.OnClickListener onActionListener(final int i) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (i < 0) {//go to previous page
                showPage(currentPage.getIndex() - 1);
            } else {
                showPage(currentPage.getIndex() + 1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Activity ProtoMain

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ProtoMain extends FragmentActivity {

private View btnRender;
private LinearLayout container;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.proto_main);

    //find view by id
    btnRender = (View)findViewById(R.id.btn_render);
    container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);

    //set event handling for button
    btnRender.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
}

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //replace fragment when clicked
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, new PDFRenderFragment());
            ft.commit();

            //gone button after all
            btnRender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
}
```

Logcat report:

```
 04-13 16:53:50.250 306-1625/? E/AudioMixer: setEqBand
 04-13 16:53:50.301 10104-10104/? E/Fragment: not create document. Error:
 04-13 16:53:50.335 10104-10104/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.sergehuby.seriers232, PID: 10104
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.getPageCount()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.sergehuby.seriers232.PDFRenderFragment.showPage(PDFRenderFragment.java:118)
                                                   at com.example.sergehuby.seriers232.PDFRenderFragment.onViewCreated(PDFRenderFragment.java:55)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
04-13 16:53:50.465 285-285/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/10104/oom_score_adj; errno=22
04-13 16:53:50.472 865-1077/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '158b3e48 com.example.sergehuby.seriers232/com.example.sergehuby.seriers232.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-13 16:53:50.764 10668-10695/? E/CrashMonitor: DropBoxHandler: crashhandler store:
```

Comment: I solved my problem by modifying my manifest , this is amazing. I delete the 3 lines:
=> <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"/>
=> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
=> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>